# How to mock Azure.Container to throws a Exception and don't get error

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Unit test using .netcore and xUnit. Currently, I'm mocking an Azure.Client and Azure.Container, I would like to mock the 'GetItemLinqQueryable' method from Azure.Container to throws an exception, but I get this error:

```
> Assert.IsType() Failure Expected: System.Exception Actual:  
> Moq.Language.Flow.NonVoidSetupPhrase`2
```

This is one my code block:

```
    _mockClientAudioMetadataHelper
                    .Setup(x => x.GetContainer(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .Returns(_mockContainerAudioMetadataHelper.Object);

                var result = _mockContainerAudioMetadataHelper //Container
                    .Setup(x => x.GetItemLinqQueryable<AudioFileSummaryDTO>(It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<QueryRequestOptions>()))
                    .Throws(new Exception());

                Assert.IsType<Exception>(result);
```

So In the assert line, I have the error above described it, I don't know How to mock that the container throws an exception and the assert should be true and pass the unit test.
Thank you.

Comment: You're asserting the result of the Moq setup, not the invocation. You need to actually call `GetItemLinqQueryable` (or something that calls it), inside of an `Assert.Throws`

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this problem, I did it this way:

```
//Mock Azure Client
_mockClientAudioMetadataHelper.Setup(x => x.GetContainer(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(_mockContainerAudioMetadataHelper.Object);

//Mock Azure container.
var result = _mockContainerAudioMetadataHelper
                 .Setup(c => c.GetItemQueryIterator<AudioFileSummaryDTO>(It.IsAny<QueryDefinition>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<QueryRequestOptions>()))
                 .Callback(() => throw new Exception());

            //Assert
            Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() =>
              _mockContainerAudioMetadataHelper.Object.
              GetItemQueryIterator<AudioFileSummaryDTO>(It.IsAny<QueryDefinition>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<QueryRequestOptions>())
              .ReadNextAsync()
            );
```